# @ sign in assembler?

Tags: assembly, addressing-mode

I am doing an assignment for an information systems class and the professor decided to use psuedo-assembler. He used the

```
@
```

in

```
SUB @106, -2(104), 110
```

What does that symbol mean?

Comment: Which assembler are you using to compile this code?

Comment: What processor are we talking about here?

Comment: Their are dozens, probably hundreds of different dialects for different processors and tastes. Which assembler are you talking about?

Comment: I am new to assembler, for all I know its a common symbol. Also, please read the actual text before responding with "what processor". Its psuedo-code, it doesn't have a specification.

Comment: A symbol in pseudo-assembler would mean whatever the writer of the pseudo-assembler code wants it to mean. All the more reason to ask your prof. I think [dasblinkenlight has a pretty good guess](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11214834/10077), though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In DEC's assembly languages (PDP-11, VAX) `@` means [*indirect addressing mode*](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/references/macvax/address-mode.html), i.e. an extra level of indirection.

In your case, `@106` means that the address of the operand is taken from the address `106`.

Comment: So what is the difference between that and calling 106 directly, in terms of making the SUB computation? Does it still mean I have to subtract whatever is in 106?

Comment: @user1260028 The difference between `106` and `@106` is that in the first case the address of the operand is `106`, and in the second case it's whatever is stored at the address `106`. For example, if `110` is stored at `106`, then `@106` is equivalent to `110`.

Comment: Ok so if say 106 is holding the value 101 (as it in the table provided), then I have to actually subtract the contents of 101 rather than 106?

Comment: @user1260028 Yes, this is correct. If you are familiar with `C`, the term *indirection* means adding an asterisk `*` in front of a pointer. Since you can *interpret* any number as a pointer in assembly language, you can think of `@` as roughly corresponding to C's asterisk `*`.